# Hi I can't see my website using ip adress

Tags: apache2, vps

I owned a vps for testing purposes and I installed apache2, but when I try to visit my site in a browser [I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYnG1.png)

I visited several links, so I verified things like if my apache2 is running using: `sudo systemctl status apache2` and I got this message:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset:
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-08 09:41:18 -03; 11min ago
  Process: 1599 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 1642 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
 Main PID: 1652 (apache2)
    Tasks: 55 (limit: 4606)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─1652 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1654 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1656 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 08 09:41:18 cercal.vhn.cl systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 08 09:41:18 cercal.vhn.cl systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Also i checked my UFW status and:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
990/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
56556                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

I checked too my ports.conf:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

And got this:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Also checking my 000-default i got this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

So, aparently everything seems to be ok I don't know what I am missing to make this thing work, any suggestion or help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, I was trying to access like https://my.example.ip.thing instead of http://my.example.ip.thing no